# MUI/Icon makes everything dissapear

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, jsx

When I try to import and use a mui icon in react, it makes the whole div dissapear, and just the background image remain, i have installed: emotion/react, emotion/styled, mui/icons-material, mui/material, styled-components, mui/styled-engine-sc

```
        <div className="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div className="form">
            <EmailIcon className='icon'/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email"></input>
            <input type="password" placeholder='Password'></input>
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
            <button id='login'>Login</button>
            <button id='register'>Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have have an error being thrown in the console.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@emotion/react', but I installed it

Comment: Depending on your environment, you may need to restart your build/server after you install. Most watching operations do not monitor changes to node_modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code, installed the dependencies and it worked just fine for me. I suggest updating these dependencies:

`npm update @mui/material @mui/icons-material @emotion/styled @emotion/react`